# How to save value from totals row in filtered subform to use in another calculation

Tags: ms-access

Trying to find out if there is code to extract the value from the totals row in a filtered subform so that I can use that total in another calculation on the parent form.

I have a form: frmMain, which is bound to tblCustomers,  a subform made from a query: qryDeliveries thesubform is just a datasheet, bound to the parent by way of CustomerID, with the totals row set to total two different fields: wage, tip. frmMain has a set of text boxes to enter in dates in order to filter qryDeliveries by that range. There are two sets of these boxes.  One filters by WageDate and the other by TipDate. txtWageStart, txtWageEnd, txtTipStart, txtTipEnd

What I'm trying to do is to add another text box somewhere on the frmMain, call it txtTotal and after filtering for WageDate, the sum of the wage column is saved, and then after filtering for the TipDate, the sum of the Tip column is saved.  Then both of those numbers added together to give me a combined total and this combined total is display in txtTotal.

I'm quite certain my whole layout is not quite the normal way it would be done, but I know very little about Access, and have spent weeks just piecing what I have together so far, trying to learn, but just about everything about vba is still a mystery as well as what is actually capable of being done or not.

any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you using different date ranges for each filter action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reference calculations generated by setting Totals row of a datasheet. Put textboxes in subform's footer section with expression to sum: `=Sum([field name])`. The textboxes will not display but can be referenced.

`=[subform container name].Form.[textboxname]`